# Relational tables should contain data and not logic - correct?

Tags: database-design, design-pattern

Ok, I couldn't find a better title, to be honest.

I'm recently landed in a new working place, and I've been asked to help with the DB. I wanted to try to explain a concept, but I'm not sure how to word it at best, and maybe this concept has already a better explanation and a name, too. I don't label myself as a DB expert, so I'd like to present them something more official than my own point of view, no matter how many good DBs I've designed in my life.

One of the things I've found mostly amusing (but not in a good way) is that they seems to follow design the db according to the logic of the problem and not according to "this is a database, it should contain data", so for example to know if an element is in a certain category, the query goes this way (in pseudocode):

```
SELECT Column1, Column2...ColumnN 
FROM Invoices [LIST OF JOIN]
WHERE
Invoces.Field1 IN 
    (TableA WHERE TableA.Field NOT IN 
        (TableB WHERE TableB.Field IN ((TableC WHERE) OR (TableD WHERE)))
OR Invoces.Field1 NOT IN 
    (TableB WHERE TableB.Field IN ((TableC WHERE) AND (TableD WHERE))
OR TableB.Field IN 
    (TableC WHERE TableC.Field IN (TableC WHERE))
OR TableB.Field NOT IN 
    (TableC WHERE TableC.Field NOT IN (TableD WHERE))
```

and so on and on for other twenty conditions or so. No, I'm not joking.

This happens because instead of saying "this is an invoice and its category is an attribute of the invoice itself", they go all the way with things like "the invoice is been inserted by that user, in that day, and he could have inserted it into a certain department or none at all, and in case of the department then that department could be part of a certain structure..." and so on. It's not even a matter of referential integrity, there are no FKs at all in this case...

Another practical example is the date of last edit of a document: instead of being stored as an attribute, it's calculated by a function which goes something along this way:

> if that document is related to another, then if the other is this
>   kind, then if the first document is related to this other document
>   too, then the date of last edit is the date when the administrator has
>   printed the daily appointment calendar"...

clearly with a bunch of else for every if, too. AND, it's not because there is some sort of dependencies, it's just because many things are stored to reflect their logic.

In a way I'd be tempted to say "write once, read many", with the meaning of "write that attribute once and then read it for free as many times as you need", because we have a low frequency of writes and a very high frequency of reads, and clearly all reads must every time recalculate everything. But I've got a feeling there must be some principle that says that you should design databases to hold data...

Comment: That look like bad design to me. Certain DB is related to the problem need to be solved so DB always should contain some logic. Hierarcy of tables and relations can be built in many ways. Some of them are unclear and obfuscated. But that doesn't mean that DB should be the plain storage. Many people treat DB such way but that is only another case of bad design.

Comment: `no FKs at all in this case` - been there, done that, got the the t-shirt. I was new on the job on site with a client which controlled the rail infrastructure of a major European country. You can imagine how many "widgets" they had. So I ran a query to get an idea of PK->FK relationships. My query returned **no** results! Thinking I had made a mistake, I asked a senior programmer - who responded **with pride" that there were "no FKs - all searches were done on PKs"! (WTF?). You could try suggest adding "last_modified" to last_edit"? You have my deepest condolences - I'd be getting my cv ready!

Comment: @Vérace: I know what you mean, but this time to be honest...I'm really happy about this new job and the company :-) They are not bad, they simply lack a decent system architect. The devs are good, the manager are nice, the company is lovely and modern, they just had the wrong approach to design: for every problem it is "well, first one to get there will solve it somehow". But I can point my finger at things and they enthusiastically jump on "you are right, let's change it", and it's an amazingly positive feeling :-)

Comment: Great stuff - I retract what I wrote above - sounds like they're willing to listen - such opportunities are rare - grab with both hands!

Comment: (plus they pay me a salary which would be more than decent in a high income country, but we are actually in a low income country, which is not that bad :-D)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## It Depends

The purpose of a database is to store `valid data` in a secure fashion for multiple users across multiple applications.

Some of the logic will focus on the `valid data` portion of that statement.  These will be your `constraints` and `data types`.

Other parts of code within the database will focus on the `multiple applications` portion.  For example, a `VIEW` will hide some complex logic to ensure that all applications see the data in an identical manner.  One application could be a web based application, the other application could be a 3rd party report generator.

## OLTP

Within an OLTP system, the complex `SELECT` statement and the `last modified date` logic doesn't make much sense.

If this is suppose to be an OLTP system, you should try to change things so that they follow normal relational database practices.

## Data Warehouse

The complexity of your pseudo-code `SELECT` statement and your `date of last edit` logic makes perfect sense in a Data Warehouse [DW] environment.  However, they are probably part of an [ETL/ELT process](http://www.jamesserra.com/archive/2012/01/difference-between-etl-and-elt/) for materializing the data into a denormalized table for faster report generation.

The `TABLES` and `VIEWS` and `MATERIALIZED VIEWS` are built to solve a very specific set of business problems.  From my experience, those objects are used as the source for various Business Reports.  In some cases, one table/view per report is created to solve a Business Requirement.

No `FKs`?  That's probably normal for a DW.  The data in the tables could be refreshed with `TRUNCATE` followed by `INSERT...SELECT`.  In this situation, a `Foreign Key` could do more harm than good.

As I read the comments, it seams your company needs to move to a more formal OLTP hierarchical design.  I wish you luck.